# Java check multiple string inside a list

Tags: java, regex

My Java code look as below;

```
public List<Lookup> findAll(List<String> types, String lang) {
    Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Lookup.myQuery");
    List<Lookup> result = new ArrayList<Lookup>();

    for (String type : types) {

        // check if isValidLookupTypeOrCode(type) && isValidLang(lang))
        // if yes, do query.setParameter("lookupTypes", types) & query.setParameter("lang", lang);
        // result = query.getResultList();
    }

    return result;
}

private boolean isValidLookupTypeOrCode(String s) {
    String pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9\\_]*$";
    if (s.matches(pattern)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isValidLang(String s) {
        String pattern= "[a-zA-Z]{1,3}$";
        if (s.matches(pattern)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Now how do I update the code inside my findAll() method, as I need to check if each of the string inside List types passes the regex (isValidLookupTypeOrCode) and the single string lang also passes the regex (isValidLang)

What is the best way to check for the 2 conditions ? since isValidLang() needs to be actually checked just once, but isValidLookupTypeOrCode() needs to be run on each string of the list ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
public List<Lookup> findAll(List<String> types, String lang) {
    List<Lookup> result = new ArrayList<Lookup>();

    // validate lang parameter
    if (isValidLang(lang)) {  
       // validate each of the type parameters from list        
       for (String type : types) {    
          if ( !isValidLookupTypeOrCode(type) )
             return result;
       }

       // we are here, all good so run the query
       Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("Lookup.myQuery");
       query.setParameter("lookupTypes", types);
       query.setParameter("lang", lang);
       result = query.getResultList();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use Java 8 then this is a good use case for streams:

```
if (isValidLang(lang)
    && types.stream().allMatch(MyClass::isValidLookupTypeOrCode)) {
    ...
}
```